# all combinations instead of using if and elifs

Tags: python, if-statement, tkinter

Is there any other way than using multiple if and elif statements for the combinations below:

This is the Code that generates all the combinations that I want:

```
import itertools

a = ['open', 'high', 'low', 'close', 'volume']
for i in range(1,len(a)+1):
    print(list(itertools.combinations(a,i)))

[('open',), ('high',), ('low',), ('close',), ('volume',)]
[('open', 'high'), ('open', 'low'), ('open', 'close'), ('open', 'volume'), ('high', 'low'), ('high', 'close'), ('high', 'volume'), ('low', 'close'), ('low', 'volume'), ('close', 'volume')]
[('open', 'high', 'low'), ('open', 'high', 'close'), ('open', 'high', 'volume'), ('open', 'low', 'close'), ('open', 'low', 'volume'), ('open', 'close', 'volume'), ('high', 'low', 'close'), ('high', 'low', 'volume'), ('high', 'close', 'volume'), ('low', 'close', 'volume')]
[('open', 'high', 'low', 'close'), ('open', 'high', 'low', 'volume'), ('open', 'high', 'close', 'volume'), ('open', 'low', 'close', 'volume'), ('high', 'low', 'close', 'volume')]
[('open', 'high', 'low', 'close', 'volume')]
```

Right now my code looks something  like this:

```
if self.average_open.get() and self.average_low.get() and self.average_high.get() and self.average_close.get() and self.average_volume.get():
    print("You got Open, Low, High, Close, and Volume")
elif self.average_open.get() and self.average_low.get() and self.average_high and self.average_close.get():
    print("You got Open, Low, High, and Close")
elif.........
```

Basically I have to do this for all the combinations that's listed from the code that generates all the combinations and I have a total of 31 elif statements...... Is there any way to do this ?

Comment: seems to me you could print "You got " and then do a single if to add each adjective if needed. You would need to be a little careful with the commas and the and, probably by having a counter of how many adjectives you have actually printed so far.

Answer (score 1):

Here's my suggestion: create a list of all possible checks and corresponding descriptors; then apply the checks in a list comprehension and select the successful descriptors:

```
actions = [(self.average_open.get, "Open"), (self.average_low.get, "Low"),\
           (self.average_high.get, "High"), (self.average_close.get, "Close"),\
           (self.average_volume.get, "Volume")]
print("You got " + ", ".join(word for fun,word in actions if fun())
```

Comment: what is 'fun()' and 'fun' in (word for fun,word in actions if fun()) ?

Comment: A function call and a function name, respectively.

Answer (score 0):

You could use something like this to create your string to be printed:

```
def createMessage():
    switches = [self.average_open.get(), self.average_low.get(), self.average_height.get(), self.average_close.get(), self.average_volume.get()]
    options = ["Open", "Low", "Height", "Close", "Volume"]
    gotten = []
    for switch, option in zip(switches, options):
        if switch:
            gotten.append(option)
    return "You got " + ", ".join(gotten)
```

Comment: Use `zip()` instead of `enumerate()` for a more pythonic solution.